# Flexbox Layout - equal heights and fittext

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fittextjs

I am trying to build a basic user interface using flexbox, I have this so far..

```css
  body,html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  }
  
  .container {
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }

  .top {
    flex:4;
    display:flex;
    background:wheat;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .bottom {
    flex:1;
    background:teal;
  }

  .bottom_content {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }

  .section1 {
    flex:1;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
  }

  .section2 {
    flex:1;
  }
  
  .btn {
    background:red;
    color:white;
    padding:20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="top">
    <span>TOP CONTENT</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bottom">
    
    <div class="bottom_content">
      
      <div class="section1">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacus quam, blandit non lacus in, venenatis tempor dolor. Aliquam in lectus lacus. </span>
      </div>
      
      <div class="section2">
        <div class="btn">
          THIS IS A BUTTON
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  
  </div>

  
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve this...

[image]

How can I make the bottom section with equal height and make the content within it vertically and horizontally centered?

I am also planning on using fittext.js or similar to make the button and the text above fit into the flex item.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

The issue with your current code is that `.bottom` is not filling the available space and that the default alignment and justification is being used.

## The fix

The desired output can be achieved by doing the following:

- Remove `flex:1;` from `.section1` and `.section2`. This stops these `div`s from expanding to fill the available space
- Add `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: space-evenly;` to`.bottom_content`. This will center align and evenly space out the `.section1` and `.section2` `div`s
- Add `display: flex;` to `.bottom`. This will make `.bottom` expand to fit the available space
- Change `flex: 1;` to `flex: 1 0 auto;` on `.bottom`. This will stop `.bottom` from reducing in size when the height of the window is small

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  flex: 4;
  display: flex;
  background: wheat;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bottom {
  /*Change*/
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: teal;
  /*Add*/
  display: flex;
}

.bottom_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*Add*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.section1 {
  /*Remove*/
  /*flex:1;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section2 {
  /*Remove*/
  /*flex:1;*/
}

.btn {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <span>TOP CONTENT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="bottom_content">
      <div class="section1">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacus quam, blandit non lacus in, venenatis tempor dolor. Aliquam in lectus lacus. </span>
      </div>
      <div class="section2">
        <div class="btn">
          THIS IS A BUTTON
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixes that layout nicely!  When I get down to smaller screensizes the flexbox item heights start to change.  Is there a way I can lock the sizes in to prevent this?

Comment: No problem. Which heights in particular are you looking to restrict?

Comment: i want section1 and section2 to keep the height ratio ie; always 50% height.  Then I am planning on using something like fittext.js to resize the text to fit

Comment: As the screen width gets smaller the bottom boxes increase in height.  I am trying to make it so they keep their height

Comment: @fightstarr20 I'm not sure I understand what you are after, the container will expand to ensure the text fits inside it. Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/h4ts2qrt/1/

Comment: Kind of, it was enough for me to modify to suit.  Thanks very much for the help!  Now to try and combine it with fittext.js

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to be of at least some assistance with your second issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented some of your code. Please Check

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  flex: 4;
  display: flex;
  background: wheat;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 1;
  background: teal;
}

.bottom_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section1 {
  <!-- flex: 1;
  -->font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.btn {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="top">
    <span>TOP CONTENT</span>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">

    <div class="bottom_content">

      <div class="section1">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacus quam, blandit non lacus in, venenatis tempor dolor. Aliquam in lectus lacus. </div>
        <button class="btn">
          THIS IS A BUTTON
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="section2"> -->
      <!-- <div class="btn"> -->
      <!-- THIS IS A BUTTON -->
      <!-- </div> -->
      <!-- </div> -->

    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content:center` and `display:flex` is the key.

you can adjust margin as you wish,besides it should do the trick.

```
.bottom_content {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   margin-top: 20px;
}

.section2 {
   flex: 1;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
   background: red;
   color: white;
   padding: 20px;
   width: fit-content;
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```